# Using an NSString as UIAlertView message:

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, uialertview

I can't figure out why this won't work, I've tried it 100 ways. The AlertView shows up with a blank message. Here's my code:

```
eventChoiceNow = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hurry Up!" message:timeTillRest delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

timeTillRest is an NSString. and just before calling the alertview an `NSLog(@"%@",timeTillRest);` displays the string without trouble.

Comment: Are you 100% sure `timeTillRest` is a `NSString`? Just wondering why this wouldn't work, since it's the simplest possible use case of `UIAlertView`. Just FYI, `%@` works also with Foundation classes other than `NSString`. How about `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([timeTillRest class]));`?

Comment: I'm sure, `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *timeTillRest;` in my .h, it's synthesized in my .m also.

Comment: Where do you define your "UIAlertView *eventChoiceNow"? Try define in this code, where you write itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you use an alertview as an instance variable? There's no need for that. It's just as easy as this:

```
UIAlertView *eventChoiceNow = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hurry Up!" message:timeTillRest delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[eventChoiceNow show];
[eventChoiceNow release];
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. You're right, no sense in declaring a UIAlertView as an instance variable.

Answer (score 2):

This should work just fine.  Testing using this code:

```
NSString *timeTillRest = @"Testing";

    UIAlertView *eventChoiceNow = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hurry Up!" message:timeTillRest delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [eventChoiceNow show];
```

And it works fine.  Also testing using:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *timeTillRest;
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize timeTillRest;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    timeTillRest = @"Testing";

    UIAlertView *eventChoiceNow = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hurry Up!" message:timeTillRest delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [eventChoiceNow show];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

And that works flawlessly too.  Make sure you aren't setting that property to nil anywhere.